# Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets: How to delete and insert 2 columns of new data in efficient way

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-gdata

The case:

1. Spreadsheets that have 2 columns with data. The columns are named "first name" and "last name".
   Some examples of datasets: "John Bond" and "Stive Colins" etc.
2. I need to delete the above columns data and insert some new data into these columns.
3. It should be done in an efficient way with Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets class.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use updateRow or deleteRow

```
$updatedListEntry = $spreadsheetService->updateRow($oldListEntry,
                                                   $newRowData);

$spreadsheetService->deleteRow($listEntry);
```

I feel update row is better option as it is one request, in case of delete row u need to delete and reinsert it needs to call api twice

Comment: Can you please write the code more specific to my question?I try this also before - not working